# How do I rotate an object about its z axis to always point in the mouse direction? (2D, OpenGL, C++, Win32, Top Down))

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d

I have a character drawn on the screen that I can move around with the arrow keys etc...

I am trying to rotate the character to face the position the mouse is in. For example the player is a sprite with a gun, I always want the tip of the gun facing the mouse.

At the moment the character is rotating, but not as I want it to. For example if the mouse is on the left hand side of the window (and the character is facing left) and then if the mouse is just moved straight across to the right side of the screen then the character will face right.
Note: This is a top down game so I have no need to change the sprite etc.

I have included my main class where the win32 window is created and the mouse is controlled.

Main class:

```
#include "Game.h"



//OPENGL FUNCTION PROTOTYPES
void display();             //called in winmain to draw everything to the screen
void reshape(int width, int height);
void init();                //called in winmain when the program starts.

//*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+* DeltaTime Stuff +*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*
double timerFrequencyRecip = 1.0;
double prevDeltaT = 1.0;
__int64 prevTime = 0;
bool initialisedPrevDeltaT = false;
//*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+* DeltaTime Stuff +*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*

int mouse_x = 0, mouse_y = 0;
bool LeftPressed = false;
int screenWidth = 1280, screenHeight = 800;
bool keys[256];
Game * game;


/*************    START OF OPENGL FUNCTIONS   ****************/
void display()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

game->draw();

glFlush();

}
void reshape(int width, int height) {
screenWidth = width; screenHeight = height;

glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

gluOrtho2D(0, screenWidth, 0, screenHeight);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
}

void init()
{
glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);



game = new Game(screenWidth, screenHeight);


game->startGame();
}

/**************** END OPENGL FUNCTIONS *************************/

//WIN32 functions
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);   // Declaration For WndProc
void KillGLWindow();                                    // releases and destroys the window
bool CreateGLWindow(char* title, int width, int height); //creates the window
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int);  // Win32 main function

                                                   //win32 global        variabless
HDC         hDC = NULL;     // Private GDI Device Context
HGLRC       hRC = NULL;     // Permanent Rendering Context
HWND        hWnd = NULL;    // Holds Our Window Handle
HINSTANCE   hInstance;      // Holds The Instance Of The Application


                        /******************* WIN32 FUNCTIONS ***************************/
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE    hInstance,          // Instance
HINSTANCE   hPrevInstance,      // Previous Instance
LPSTR       lpCmdLine,          // Command Line Parameters
int         nCmdShow)           // Window Show State
{
MSG     msg;                                    // Windows Message Structure
bool    done = false;                               // Bool Variable To Exit Loop

// Create Our OpenGL Window
if (!CreateGLWindow("Game", screenWidth, screenHeight))
{
    return 0;                                   // Quit If Window Was Not Created
}

while (!done)                                   // Loop That Runs While done=FALSE
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))   // Is There A Message Waiting?
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)             // Have We Received A Quit Message?
        {
            done = true;                            // If So done=TRUE
        }
        else                                    // If Not, Deal With Window Messages
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);             // Translate The Message
            DispatchMessage(&msg);              // Dispatch The Message
        }
    }
    else                                        // If There Are No Messages
    {
        if (keys[VK_ESCAPE])
            done = true;
    }
    //*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+* DeltaTime Stuff +*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*
    LARGE_INTEGER t;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t);
    __int64 currentTime = t.QuadPart;
    __int64 ticksElapsed = currentTime - prevTime;
    double deltaT = double(ticksElapsed) * timerFrequencyRecip;
    if (!initialisedPrevDeltaT) {
        prevDeltaT = deltaT;
        deltaT = 0.0025;
        initialisedPrevDeltaT = true;
    }
    prevTime = currentTime;
    prevDeltaT = deltaT;

    deltaT *= 6;

    //*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+* DeltaTime Stuff +*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*
    display();                  // Draw The Scene

    SwapBuffers(hDC);               // Swap Buffers (Double Buffering)

    game->update(deltaT);                   // update variables
    game->processKeys(keys);            //process keyboard


}

// Shutdown
KillGLWindow();                                 // Kill The Window
return (int)(msg.wParam);                       // Exit The Program
}

//WIN32 Processes function - useful for responding to user inputs or other events.
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND   hWnd,           // Handle For This Window
UINT    uMsg,           // Message For This Window
WPARAM  wParam,         // Additional Message Information
LPARAM  lParam)         // Additional Message Information
{
switch (uMsg)                                   // Check For Windows Messages
{
case WM_CLOSE:                              // Did We Receive A Close Message?
{
    PostQuitMessage(0);                     // Send A Quit Message
    return 0;                               // Jump Back
}
break;

case WM_SIZE:
{
    reshape(LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
    return 0;
}
break;

case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
{
    mouse_x = LOWORD(lParam);
    mouse_y = screenHeight - HIWORD(lParam);
    LeftPressed = true;
}
break;

case WM_LBUTTONUP:
{
    LeftPressed = false;
}
break;

case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{
    mouse_x = LOWORD(lParam);
    mouse_y = screenHeight - HIWORD(lParam);
    game->moveMouse(mouse_x, mouse_y);

}
break;
case WM_KEYDOWN:                            // Is A Key Being Held Down?
{
    keys[wParam] = true;                    // If So, Mark It As TRUE
    return 0;                               // Jump Back
}
break;
case WM_KEYUP:                              // Has A Key Been Released?
{
    keys[wParam] = false;                   // If So, Mark It As FALSE
    return 0;                               // Jump Back
}
break;
}

// Pass All Unhandled Messages To DefWindowProc
return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void KillGLWindow()                             // Properly Kill The Window
{
if (hRC)                                            // Do We Have A Rendering Context?
{
    if (!wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL))                    // Are We Able To Release The DC And RC Contexts?
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Release Of DC And RC Failed.", "SHUTDOWN ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }

    if (!wglDeleteContext(hRC))                     // Are We Able To Delete The RC?
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Release Rendering Context Failed.", "SHUTDOWN ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
    hRC = NULL;                                     // Set RC To NULL
}

if (hDC && !ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC))                   // Are We Able To Release The DC
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Release Device Context Failed.", "SHUTDOWN ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    hDC = NULL;                                     // Set DC To NULL
}

if (hWnd && !DestroyWindow(hWnd))                   // Are We Able To Destroy The Window?
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Could Not Release hWnd.", "SHUTDOWN ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    hWnd = NULL;                                        // Set hWnd To NULL
}

if (!UnregisterClass("OpenGL", hInstance))          // Are We Able To Unregister Class
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Could Not Unregister Class.", "SHUTDOWN ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    hInstance = NULL;                                   // Set hInstance To NULL
}
}

/*  This Code Creates Our OpenGL Window.  Parameters Are:                   *
*   title           - Title To Appear At The Top Of The Window              *
*   width           - Width Of The GL Window Or Fullscreen Mode             *
*   height          - Height Of The GL Window Or Fullscreen Mode            */

bool CreateGLWindow(char* title, int width, int height)
{
GLuint      PixelFormat;            // Holds The Results After Searching For A Match
WNDCLASS    wc;                     // Windows Class Structure
DWORD       dwExStyle;              // Window Extended Style
DWORD       dwStyle;                // Window Style
RECT        WindowRect;             // Grabs Rectangle Upper Left / Lower Right Values
WindowRect.left = (long)0;          // Set Left Value To 0
WindowRect.right = (long)width;     // Set Right Value To Requested Width
WindowRect.top = (long)0;               // Set Top Value To 0
WindowRect.bottom = (long)height;       // Set Bottom Value To Requested Height

RECT        rect;
GetClientRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &rect);
rect.left = (rect.right / 2) - (width / 2);
rect.top = (rect.bottom / 2) - (height / 2);

hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);              // Grab An Instance For Our Window
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;  // Redraw On Size, And Own DC For Window.
wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;                  // WndProc Handles Messages
wc.cbClsExtra = 0;                                  // No Extra Window Data
wc.cbWndExtra = 0;                                  // No Extra Window Data
wc.hInstance = hInstance;                           // Set The Instance
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);         // Load The Default Icon
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);           // Load The Arrow Pointer
wc.hbrBackground = NULL;                                    // No Background Required For GL
wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;                                 // We Don't Want A Menu
wc.lpszClassName = "OpenGL";                                // Set The Class Name

if (!RegisterClass(&wc))                                    // Attempt To Register The Window Class
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Failed To Register The Window Class.", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;                                           // Return FALSE
}


dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;         // Window Extended Style
dwStyle = WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX;

AdjustWindowRectEx(&WindowRect, dwStyle, FALSE, dwExStyle);     // Adjust Window To True Requested Size

                                                                // Create The Window
if (!(hWnd = CreateWindowEx(dwExStyle,                          // Extended Style For The Window
    "OpenGL",                           // Class Name
    title,                              // Window Title
    dwStyle,
    rect.left,
    rect.top,
    WindowRect.right - WindowRect.left,
    WindowRect.bottom - WindowRect.top,
    NULL,                               // No Parent Window
    NULL,                               // No Menu
    hInstance,                          // Instance
    NULL)))                             // Dont Pass Anything To WM_CREATE
{
    KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Error.", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;                               // Return FALSE
}


static  PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd =             // pfd Tells Windows How We Want Things To Be
{
    sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),              // Size Of This Pixel Format Descriptor
    1,                                          // Version Number
    PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |                        // Format Must Support Window
    PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |                        // Format Must Support OpenGL
    PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,                           // Must Support Double Buffering
    PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                              // Request An RGBA Format
    24,                                     // Select Our Color Depth
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                           // Color Bits Ignored
    0,                                          // No Alpha Buffer
    0,                                          // Shift Bit Ignored
    0,                                          // No Accumulation Buffer
    0, 0, 0, 0,                                 // Accumulation Bits Ignored
    24,                                         // 24Bit Z-Buffer (Depth Buffer)  
    0,                                          // No Stencil Buffer
    0,                                          // No Auxiliary Buffer
    PFD_MAIN_PLANE,                             // Main Drawing Layer
    0,                                          // Reserved
    0, 0, 0                                     // Layer Masks Ignored
};

if (!(hDC = GetDC(hWnd)))                           // Did We Get A Device Context?
{
    KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
    MessageBox(NULL, "Can't Create A GL Device Context.", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;                               // Return FALSE
}

if (!(PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd)))  // Did Windows Find A Matching Pixel Format?
{
    KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
    MessageBox(NULL, "Can't Find A Suitable PixelFormat.", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;                               // Return FALSE
}

if (!SetPixelFormat(hDC, PixelFormat, &pfd))        // Are We Able To Set The Pixel Format?
{
    KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
    MessageBox(NULL, "Can't Set The PixelFormat.", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;                               // Return FALSE
}

if (!(hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC)))             // Are We Able To Get A Rendering Context?
{
    KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
    MessageBox(NULL, "Can't Create A GL Rendering Context.", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;                               // Return FALSE
}

if (!wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC))                  // Try To Activate The Rendering Context
{
    KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
    MessageBox(NULL, "Can't Activate The GL Rendering Context.", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;                               // Return FALSE
}


ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);                      // Show The Window
SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);                      // Slightly Higher Priority
SetFocus(hWnd);                                 // Sets Keyboard Focus To The Window
reshape(width, height);

init();


//*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+* DeltaTime Stuff +*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*

LARGE_INTEGER f;
if (!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&f)) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Cannot get performance counter frequency", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;
}
timerFrequencyRecip = 1.0 / double(f.QuadPart);

LARGE_INTEGER t;
if (!QueryPerformanceCounter(&t)) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Cannot get performance counter value", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;
}
prevTime = t.QuadPart;
//*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+* DeltaTime Stuff +*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*

return true;                                    // Success
}
```

Below is where I am trying to rotate the character

```
void Character::draw() {
setTexture();
glLoadIdentity();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, e_texture);
double angleInRadians = std::atan2(mouse_y, mouse_x);
double angleInDegrees = (angleInRadians / M_PI) * 180;
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glTranslatef(e_x, e_y, 0);
glRotatef(angleInDegrees, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(0, e_height);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(e_width, e_height);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(e_width, 0);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract the position of your character from the position of your mouse (I assume they are in the same space).

So if you show your character at `e_x, e_y` then you get the angle with `atan2(mouse_y - e_y, mouse_x - e_x)`.

Answer (score 0):

do you know `glulookat` ? It is useful for 3D version.

In this case you does not need the atan function, I suppose mouse_x and mouse_y are the **deltas** between your subject and the mouse, If you normalize it you get the cosine and the sine of the desired angle, from them you can create a [rotation matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html) and do glMultMatrix.

I hope to help,
Regards.